# Foreign key constraint fails on many to many Hibernate relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, foreign-keys, many-to-many, liquibase

I'm currently trying implement a many to many relationship in Hibernate. I followed: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-many-to-many however I'm getting an exception that says:

```
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`playlist_comparer`.`playlist_tracks`, CONSTRAINT `fk_pt_track_id` FOREIGN KEY (`track_id`) REFERENCES `tracks` (`id`))
```

Here's the liquibase for my join table:

```
        - createTable:
        tableName: playlist_tracks
        columns:
          - column:
              constraints:
                primaryKey: true
                primaryKeyName: pk_playlist_track_id
              name: id
              type: bigint
              autoIncrement: true
          - column:
              name: playlist_id
              type: VARCHAR(255)
              constraints:
                foreignKeyName: fk_pt_playlist_id
                references: playlists(id)
          - column:
              name: track_id
              type: VARCHAR(255)
              constraints:
                foreignKeyName: fk_pt_track_id
                references: tracks(id)
```

and the mapping on my Hibernate objects:

Playlist.java:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinTable(name = "playlist_tracks", //
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "track_id", nullable = false)}, //
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "playlist_id", nullable = false)})
private Set<Track> tracks = new HashSet<>();
```

Track.java:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tracks")
private Set<Playlist> playlists = new HashSet<>();
```

I save the tracks into the DB first with no association to any playlists in one @Transactional method, leave the transactional boundary and then enter a new @Transactional method where I add the tracks to the Playlist object and then try to save that at which point I get the exception at the top.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I just had the join columns the wrong way round on the join table annotation.